# Make border fit to Div

Tags: html, css

Hello Stackoverflow I have a problem as the border of my buttons can't seem to fit responsively to the div

Here is a codepen that shows the border of the button won't align
How do I fix this?
Please notice this uses bootstrap :)
http://bit.ly/1EFpebs

Comment: can you elaborate more? how border is causing any trouble?

Comment: reset the vertical padding of topmenuwrap to 0 and set li as inline-block display http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azaVYx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're worried about the height add this.

```
.topMenuWrap, .container-fluid, .topMenu{
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;

}
```

if you're worried about the width you need to set the width of your div somehow.

```
.topMenuWrap{
max-width:25%;
}
```